# Pointer to incomplete class type is not allowed?

Tags: c, linked-list

I am new to C and am using visual studio.
While writing this function I got this error(Pointer to incomplete class type is not allowed). I don't know why.

```
int Length(struct node* head) 
{
  struct node* current = head;
  int count = 0;
  while (current != NULL) 
   {
     count++;
     current = current->next;  <-- error here when pointing current to next
   }
  return count;
}
```

Comment: add the definition of node please.

Comment: How have you declared `struct node`?

Comment: show your struct definition

Comment: @EdHeal Yes, i did, i just looked at my code again, was using wrong names. But thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The `->` operator dereferences the expression to its left. So at this point the concrete layout of this object must be known. The `struct node* current=head` line declares a pointer to a struct (where this struct can be opaque) when the definition of this struct is not seen by the compiler. To get this code to work, you need to include the definition of struct node into the compilation unit (=C mumble for file) where you use the struct.

Answer (score 0):

The error of your compiler sounds incorrect. What is not allowed is accessing the inner properties of incomplete type, because it requires knowledge of it's internals. `current->next` is an attempt to get internal data from pointer to incomplete type. If you want to do that, you need to include the full type definition of you `struct node` in the same `.c` file or included `.h` file (header).